# What is the intended way to set `cpupower` on boot?

Tags: linux, rhel, power-management, oracle-linux, cpu-frequency

Running `cpupower frequency-set -g powersave` is a one-shot.  I could think of a number of ways to make this happen on boot (rc.local, systemd one-shot, etc)...

**Question**:  Is there a "correct" way to set `cpupower` flags at boot?

The OS is Oracle Linux 9 (ie RHEL9, Rocky 9, Alma 9), but hopefully the setting is distro-agnostic.